# Parsing the OGR style string in Java

Tags: gdal, ogr, java

I am using the GDAL Java bindings to load vector data sets into a Java based GIS application.

The [GDAL Java bindings](http://gdal.org/java/) seem to contain no classes or methods to parse the `Feature#getStyleString` into something I can easily work with. Looking at the native GDAL code, there exist classes like [`OGRStyleTool`](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRStyleTool.html) and enumerations like [`ogr_style_tool_class_id`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#ae392af0d0b0305cea3b85f529cd25cc6) which do the parsing for you.

What are my Java options if I want to extract the styling information from the style string ? Do I have to write my own parser for this, or am I overlooking another option ?